# regular expression to extract multiline line from a file in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to extract multiline line from a file that has system call trace.   I try to find a system call trace for the error that happens.  It is a debugging project.
My goal to extract all line between keywords "Before Error" and "After Error"
Here are my tries.
https://repl.it/@kaloon/LiquidDimgrayParser

May I know what a problem with it?

Comment: Can you post an example error message? It's hard to write any regex pattern without seeing knowing exactly what the text looks like.

Comment: the text available on the link at the main post. Just click on the link

Comment: @kaloon: It is actually preferred here to have searchable code within the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(".*Before Error(.*)After Error.*", re.DOTALL)
pattern.findall(str1)
```

Comment: I updated it with a working version, tested in your link.

Comment: Thanks. It works :) . But What about If I want to just extract the line between them without extract the same the line that has "Before Error " and "After Error"

Comment: Using `pattern = re.compile(".*Before Error[^\n]*\n(.*)\n.*After Error.*", re.DOTALL)` should exclude the lines containing "Before Error" and "After Error".

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried the last update. it got an empty result.

Comment: I'm not sure - for me, the second pattern returns the following:  `['[pid 16701] 16:08:36 getuid()           = 10114\n[pid 16701] 16:08:36 getuid()           = 10114\n[pid 16701] 16:08:36 ioctl(8, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fc4f92e88) = 0\n[pid 16701] 16:08:36 ioctl(8, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fc4f92e88) = 0\n\xe2\x80\xa6[pid 16701] 16:08:36 ioctl(47, ASHMEM_GET_SIZE, 0) = 84\n[pid 16701] 16:08:36 close(47)          = 0\n[pid 16701] 16:08:36 getuid()           = 10114']`